# Refactoring solutions for Swift on Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, refactoring, xcode8

Well, Xcode 8 is out and unfortunately refactoring is still not available for Swift ( Apple (ಠ_ಠ) ).

I'm trying to list all the available options for me to perform complex refactoring (renaming classes, properties used outside of the classes, methods, properties that have name collision with other properties etc..)

What I've come up until now is as follows:

- **Manually** - not an option for me (big and nested project, could result in shorter life span)
- **Search and replace** - better option, but still involves some heavy manual labor (going through each search result and applying replace, because selecting replace all is very risky on just raw text search)
- **Using AppCode refactoring option** - this option seem to be the most promising, but it's seems buggy (not replacing some of the occurrences), also the program doesn't support Xcode 8, and it costs money (I'm on the 30 trial).
  all in all, this is the best fail safe solution I can think of.

I was wondering if maybe someone else has other good ways to accomplish complex refactoring on Swift, maybe something that feel safe and robust?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe, which Swift version do you use and give some example when AppCode Rename does not work correctly for you? Btw, Xcode 8 support is ready in the free EAP which you can download here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/OBJC/AppCode+EAP and which is available for any major release.